How to resume CHHapticAdvancedPatternPlayer with AHAP with audio?
I have an AHAP which plays audio inside of it.
let patternPlayer = try hapticEngine.makeAdvancedPlayer(with: patternFile)
patternPlayer.loopEnabled = false
try patternPlayer.start(atTime: CHHapticTimeImmediate)

When I just used this code, I found out that if I put the app to the background while the haptic sequence is playing, the sound and haptics go away and don't come back.
I found out about patternPlayer.pause and patternPlayer.resume. I have started to call them upon receipt of UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification and UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification. However, for some reason neither the audio, nor haptics come back, even after I restarted the CHHapticEngine with start. I also called AVAudioSession.setActive, but this didn't help either...
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var engine: CHHapticEngine!
    var player: CHHapticAdvancedPatternPlayer!
    var engineStopped: Bool = true
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let engine = try! CHHapticEngine(audioSession: .sharedInstance())
        self.engine = engine
        
        engine.stoppedHandler = { [unowned self] reason in
            self.engineStopped = true
            print("Engine stopped reason", reason)
        }

        let player = try! engine.makeAdvancedPlayer(
            with: try! CHHapticPattern(
                contentsOf: Bundle.main.url(
                    forResource: "res",
                    withExtension: "ahap"
                )!
            )
        )

        player.loopEnabled = true
        
        player.completionHandler = { err in
            print("Audio end", err)
        }
        
        try! engine.start()
        try! player.start(atTime: CHHapticTimeImmediate)
        self.player = player
        
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(appWillResignActive),
            name: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification,
            object: nil
        )
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(appDidBecomeActive),
            name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification,
            object: nil
        )
    }
    
    @objc
    private func appWillResignActive() {
        try! player.pause(atTime: CHHapticTimeImmediate)
    }
    
    @objc
    private func appDidBecomeActive() {
        if engineStopped {
            try! engine.start()
            engineStopped = false
        }
        try! player.resume(atTime: CHHapticTimeImmediate)
    }
}


Then I decided to do the following:

on pause, I stop the original haptic player, memorizing, for how long it played
on resume, I create a new haptic player with an offset, using seek, so that it plays from where it predecessor was interrupted
I start this player

Fun fact: now it plays the haptics as expected! But not the audio...
How do I restart the audio in this scenario? I don't see any direct link to AVAudioPlayer or AVAudioEngine or something like this anywhere in memory debugger...
